# Issue retrieving http header -file path value

Tags: swift3, alamofire

I'm trying to retrieve a custom header that is returned from an HTTP Get request.  I'm able to retrieve all the other header values.

```
Alamofire.request(
            apiURL,
            parameters: ["UserID": post.userID]
            )
            .responseData { response in
                guard response.result.isSuccess else {
                    print("Error while fetching Data: \(String(describing: response.result.error))")
                    return
                }
                 if let headers = response.response?.allHeaderFields as? [String: String]{
                    if let myHeader = headers["profileImageURL"] as? String {
                        print(myHeader)
                 }
```

Using the developer tool in Chrome I can see the Header is being returned.  Perhaps I'm casting incorrectly?  The Header name is profileImageURL

[image]

Comment: Why don't you print the value of `allHeaderFields` or even better, use the debugger to inspect the value?

Comment: David.  It's turns out this is a foolish mistake passing the userID parameter to the request was such that nothing was getting passed.

Answer (score 0):

The userID parameter that I was passing to the HTTP Get was incorrect.